# Can you identify these connectors (JST or Molex type)?

Tags: connector

I am trying to identify these board-to-wire connectors found on a PCB for a garage opener. The pitch is 2mm. At first I thought they were JST PH, but the two slots are spaced a little too far apart, and a JST PH cable will not fit. The unit is sold in the US and the PCB has the year 2017 printed on it.

They are not latched, and fully shrouded, with openings only on the sides.

I have tried web searches and the [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html) but failed to find any matches.

Ideally I would like to find a ready-made cable for the 10-pin connector.

[image: 10-pin connector]
[image]

Comment: Please post pitch and dimensions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [TE AMP CT](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-292133-8.datasheet.pdf) header. Part numbers probably 292133-10 and -6.

Comment: Thank you, looks like that's the one. It seems really hard to find cable assemblies for those, I haven't found any 10-pin ones (and I'm not sure I'm up for crimping the connectors).

Comment: There appears to be a 10-pin IDC plug under the part number 1-173977-0.